# How to make this form responsive using flex box

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to make this form responsive. I need the form to stay on a single line with same width for all elements on large screens. When I change the flex direction to column the elements overflow to the top. what i need is for the form fields to stack on top of each other from medium screen sizes. Link fo codepen https://codepen.io/Nickbing/pen/RwwrOBp

```
<div class="container job-search-container">
    <div class="job-search-bar-section">
      <form class="search-form">
        <div class="search-form-group">
          <input
            id="keywords"
            type="text"
            class="search-form-input"
            placeholder="Enter Keywords"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div class="search-form-group select-item-wrapper">
          <select class="search-form-select">
             <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Categories</option>
            <option value="volvo">IT</option>
            <option value="saab">Civil</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="search-form-group select-item-wrapper">
          <select class="search-form-select">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Locations</option>
            <option value="volvo">New York</option>
            <option value="saab">California</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="search-form-group">
          <button type="submit">
            Search Jobs
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="all-jobs">
        <a href="#">all jobs</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%; // 1rem = 10px, 10px/16px = 62.5%
}

body {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', 'Source Sans Pro', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
    'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.job-search-container {
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: lightcoral;

  .job-search-bar-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;

    .search-form {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      //flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      &-group {
        flex: 1;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        //width: 100%;
         input {
          font-family: inherit;
          font-size: 2rem;
          font-weight: 400;
          padding: 2rem;
          // width: 100%;
          height: 5rem;
        }

        select {
          width: 100%;
          height: 5rem;
          font-size: 2rem;
          font-weight: 600;
          padding-left: 1rem;

        }

         button {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 100%;
          height: 5rem;
          font-size: 2rem;
          font-weight: 500;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          background-color: black;
          color: white;
          border: 0;


        }
      }
    }

    .all-jobs {
      margin-right: auto;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
  }
}

 // @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 //        .search-form {
 //    flex-direction: column;
 //    justify-content: center;
 //    align-items: center;
 //  }
 //    }
```

Edit: 
Ok, If I change the height of the .job-search-container to a fixed height it works. I need it such a way that it works with something like max-height/ take the needed space.

Comment: I see `@media` queries in your future.

Comment: try `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: also do **not** use forms on codepen it's very annoying

Answer (score 1):

step by step, apply these changes.

1.remove the page container height and set padding at the top and bottom for as you wanted.

```
.job-search-container {
  height: auto;// or remove
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
```

2.add some full with 100% defult for input field.

```
.job-search-container .job-search-bar-section .search-form-group input{
    width:100%;
 }
```

optional: for better ux remove the margin right of search-form-group in mobile level

```
@media screen(max-width:768px){
   .job-search-container .job-search-bar-section .search-form-group input{
    margin-right:0;
 }    
}
```

3. in below 768px (mobile screen) change the search-form-group width as 100% and remove the flex property using media query for mobile screens like this,

   ```
      @media screen (max-width:768px){
         .job-search-container .job-search-bar-section .search-form-group{
             flex:inherit;
             width:100%;
         }
      }
   ```

   if you have any doubt about the above code, iam right here to help you ,
   thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Quicksand', 'Source Sans Pro', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
 margin: 0PX;
}
.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.job-search-container {
 background-color: lightcoral;
 .job-search-bar-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4rem;
  .search-form {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .search-form-group {
   margin-right: 2rem;
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
   flex-grow: 1;
   input {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
   }
   select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 1rem;
   }
   button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
   }
  }
  .all-jobs {
   margin-right: auto;
   font-size: 2rem;
  }
 }
}
```